# mysql slow query for little data set

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-slow-query-log

**Describe：**

The table `profit` has about 20 columns, and no big column like `text`, and have two indexs:

1. index `idx_uid` on column `uid`
2. index `uid_acc_fId_date` on column `uid,acc,fid and date`

The slow query sql is：

```
select * from profit where (((uid='1111') and (flag=32)) and (fId='2222')) and (date='20161008') limit 1;
```

and the explain output is：

```
id:1
select_type:SIMPLE
table:profit
type:ref
possible_keys:uid_acc_fId_date
key:uid_acc_fId_date
key_len:4
ref:const
rows:267
Extra:Using where
```

Execute the sql with `sql_no_cache` will spend about 2s, and execute the same sql with `sql_no_cache` second time will spend about 0.1s.

**Env：**

1. mysql 5.5.49-37.9,innodb，percona
2. SATA HDD
3. The table profit has about one million rows
4. Centos 2.6 kernel
5. rows count for `uid=1111` is only **270**

**PS：**

**Mysql will backup everyday at midnight， and `innodb_old_blocks_time` is 0, I think the backup will flush all hot data out of buffer pool。But even so it spend too many time to do the above query。So, is it the disk problem？**

Comment: How many rows are found if you remove the `flag=32`? Because for `flag` you didn't specify an index, so mysql needs get all rows having `uid='1111' and fId='2222' and date='20161008'` and then has check each of them if the `flag` is `32`.

Comment: Thank you for your time.
And the all data rows for `uid=1111` has only 270 rows

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: It's resolved after the system migrate to AWS。。。

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon the comment above, change index uid_acc_fId_date to (uid,fid,date,acc) and change the query to:

```
SELECT columns
     , I
     , actually
     , want
  FROM profit 
 WHERE uid = 1111 
   AND fId = 2222
   AND date='20161008'
   AND flag = 32
 ORDER 
    BY uid
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use column name when you try to select query. Like SELECT name, class_name from table_name;

Comment: Thank you! It's a good suggestion, maybe I will have a try, but it's really hard for our project to do it, because there are too many to modify, and it's risky to modify the previous code. In fact, I don't think it's the key for this issue

Comment: Good advice, but probably not relevant to the sluggishness here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all parentheses in where condition. Unnecessary parentheses cause mysql can not use index correctly.

```
select * 
from profit 
where 
     uid='1111' 
     and flag=32 
     and fId='2222' 
     and date='20161008' 
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! The parentheses are added by framework. As you say, I remove all parentheses , and the explain output is same.

Comment: As you say, the all data rows for uid=1111 has only 270 rows. If the index of uid_acc_fId_date is used, it is impossible to use 2s.

Comment: The MySQL parser is good about ignoring redundant parentheses.